# How to create video from its frames iPhone

Tags: objective-c, video, avfoundation, mpmovieplayercontroller

I had done R&D and got success in how to get frames in terms of images from video file played in `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Got all frames from this code, and save all images in one Array.

```
for(int i= 1; i <= moviePlayerController.duration; i++)
{
    UIImage *img = [moviePlayerController thumbnailImageAtTime:i timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
    [arrImages addObject:img];
}
```

Now the question is that, After change some image file, like adding emotions to the images and also adding filters, such as; movie real, black and white, How can we create video again and store the same video in Document directory with the same frame rate and without losing quality of video.

After changing some images I had done following code to save that video again.

```
- (void) writeImagesAsMovie:(NSString*)path 
{
    NSError *error  = nil;
    UIImage *first = [arrImages objectAtIndex:0];
    CGSize frameSize = first.size;
    AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:
                                  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                                              error:&error];
    NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:640], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:480], AVVideoHeightKey,
                                   nil];
    AVAssetWriterInput* writerInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput
                                        assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                        outputSettings:videoSettings] retain];

    AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
                                                     assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput
                                                     sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];

    NSParameterAssert(writerInput);
    NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:writerInput]);
    [videoWriter addInput:writerInput];

    [videoWriter startWriting];
    [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

    int frameCount = 0;
    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;
    for(UIImage *img in arrImages)
    {
        buffer = [self newPixelBufferFromCGImage:[img CGImage] andFrameSize:frameSize]; 

            if (adaptor.assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) 
            {
                CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(frameCount,(int32_t) kRecordingFPS);
                [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];

                if(buffer)
                    CVBufferRelease(buffer);
            }
        frameCount++;
    } 

     [writerInput markAsFinished];
     [videoWriter finishWriting];
}


- (CVPixelBufferRef) newPixelBufferFromCGImage: (CGImageRef) image andFrameSize:(CGSize)frameSize
{
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                             nil];
    CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;
    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, frameSize.width,
                                          frameSize.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, (CFDictionaryRef) options, 
                                          &pxbuffer);
    NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL);

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
    void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);
    NSParameterAssert(pxdata != NULL);

    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, frameSize.width,
                                                 frameSize.height, 8, 4*frameSize.width, rgbColorSpace, 
                                                 kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
    NSParameterAssert(context);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0));
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image), 
                                           CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

    return pxbuffer;
}
```

I am new in this topic so please help me solve this question.

Comment: You can use

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873423/iphone-sdk-create-a-video-from-uiimage

Comment: Did you get solution for this ? Can you please post solution if possible ?

Comment: why you want to convert as video again? use images only...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can refer following links hope you get some help :-

1. http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development-advanced-discussion/77999-make-video-nsarray-uiimages.html
2. [Using FFMPEG library with iPhone SDK for video encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679649/using-ffmpeg-library-with-iphone-sdk-for-video-encoding)
3. [Iphone SDK,Create a Video from UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873423/iphone-sdk-create-a-video-from-uiimage)
4. [iOS Video Editing - Is it possible to merge (side by side not one after other) two video files into one using iOS 4 AVFoundation classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757423/ios-video-editing-is-it-possible-to-merge-side-by-side-not-one-after-other-t)

Comment: Hi is there anything updated for Swift? All these links seem old. We are trying to merge images and videos into one master video where images must appear as separate "videos" in the master video. For instance, assume 1 image and 1 one video. In the master video, the image appears for 3 seconds and then the video plays. Any advice on doing this? Thanks!